# How do I assign an Address-book admin for OpenLDAP?

Tags: server, ldap, openldap

I'm new to OpenLDAP but through tutorials and documentation I have been able to setup a LDAP Addressbook where users can retrieve email addresses and mobile numbers with their email clients (Thunderbird, Outlook). I was the one who created the entries from scratch with the LDAP Manager.

I want to create a Phone-Book entry for just name and numbers and then pass on the responsibility of keeping the Phone-Book updated to someone else. How can I assign a user read+write privileges so (s)he can be the administrator for the `ou=Phone-book` section of LDAP?.

My setup is like this:

- `ou=People` - email, name, number, address, job title, etc.
- `ou=Phone-book` - phone numbers and names
- `ou=Users` - LDAP users who login to read the address-book
- anonymous now allowed

Comment: Are you still looking for help or have you solved this problem? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!